# regular expression for blocking emails in cpanel

Tags: regex, cpanel

I have the option in cpanel to block emails with subjects equal certain words or containing certain words, which works great...
but recently I've been receiving emails with subjects such as "s$e^x(y and s!e*(x@y g$ir-ls" for example,
cpanel has the option to use regular expressions to check emails,
so basically how would I strip a string for all regular characters and see if it contains a certain word, basically I would like a regular expression that matches the following string as such:

`s$e^x(y`  contains sexy and it is mixed with special characters

or

`s$e^x(y g$ir-ls` contains 'sexy girls' and it is mixed with special characters

thanks!
i tried looking some stuff up but couldn't really match this exact condition (I'm new to regex) eventhough I did find some other useful things i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
s[^a-z]*e[^a-z]*x[^a-z]*y[^a-z]*|g[^a-z]*i[^a-z]*r[^a-z]*l[^a-z]*s[^a-z]*
```

Comment: [^a-z] means any character that is not a-z, lowercase. The * after it means it can be zero or more of them.

Comment: ah alright, great, thanks...so basically might be better to do this [^a-zA-Z] no ?

Comment: If you write "What is your sex, you have to tell." Then you will have "sexy" with non-letters in between.

Comment: Yes, [^a-zA-Z] is probably better